# Ajax call not working in yii2

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

My code:

```
$(".status").click(function () {
    var id= this.id;
    alert(id);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/dealer/change_status',
        data: "id="+id,
        success: function (response) {
    }});
});
```

On click, *id alert* show up, but ajax request doesn't work neither shows any error alert id and page refresh.

Comment: if you open a browser console (ctrl+shift+I in chrome), switch the Network tab and click on your link with ajax action what status do you see in the "/dealer/change_status" row? is there the status 200 ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

```
$(".status").click(function () {
    var id= $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax call like this. send ur id value as parameter. add one prameter to ur function change_status()

make sure you clicking on button or anchor tag. having class as status.
and make sure you have proper url. 
I think you need to add base_url. other wish it will not work.

```
$(".status").click(function () {
    var id= this.id;
    alert(id);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/dealer/change_status/"+id,
        success: function (response) {
    }});
});
```

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
return false;
```

or

```
preventDefault();
```

to preventing page refreshing. After that, you need to check in your browser is ajax call exists ot not.

Answer (score 0):

Better still, you can use it like this

```
$(".status").click(function () {
    var id= this.id;
    alert(id);

    var link = '". \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute("/dealer/change_status"). "';

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: link,
        data: {id: id },
        success: function (response) {
        //Do this as stated below
        console.log(response); //This is to know the response from the server
    }});

   return false; //Prevent form submission twice

});
```

This code above should help you achieve your purpose. Feel free to write back